# T-SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple question regarding `SELECT` statement in SQL Server. I would like to know the purpose of the following syntax:

```
SELECT column_name, . *
```

I don't understand the purpose of the (period) and a (star) after the `SELECT`. I understand `SELECT column_name1, column_name2,.... etc.` or `SELECT *...`
but what does a period do before the star.

Comment: This is not valid syntax in SqlServer

Comment: The star is used to select all fields.  The period before the star is not required. Typically the period is used to separate a table and its field.  Example "Table1.Field1".  This only becomes important when there is more than one table such as joins.

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid syntax and will not run.

`.*` can be used following a table name or [alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php) to get all columns for that table. For example...

```
SELECT mytable.* FROM mytable
```

or

```
SELECT a.column_one, a.* FROM mytable a
```